# .htaccess redirect whole site to specific url new site

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my .htaccess:

`Redirect 301 / http://newurl.com/`

But when I go to the site example `http://url.com/demo`, I redirect to `http://newurl.com/demo` but I want only `http://www.newurl.com` so everything after the slash (/) has to be cut off.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect edits by other users - some of them don't know what they're doing half the time. Your question is now formatted as it should be.

Comment: Well, that's what the Redirect directive does. If you don't want that, then use mod_rewrite instead.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newurl.com/ [R=301,L]
```